# Creating bash service on Ubuntu 17.04 with systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

I am running **Ubuntu 17.04** 64-bit and I would like to setup syncthing and two more applications to be started after the machine boots without requiring someone to log in and manually start them.

I have installed all applications into the following directories:

```
/home/msa/syncthing/
/home/msa/minecraft-server/
/home/msa/test/
```

For each of those applications I have created a bash start script with launch commands:

```
/home/msa/syncthing/start.sh
/home/msa/minecraft-server/start.sh
/home/msa/test/start.sh
```

The **syncthing** start file contains this:

```
./syncthing
```

The **minecraft-server** start file contains this:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

The **test** start file contains this:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar test.jar
```

---

I found, that this version of Ubuntu uses *systemd*, and created a file named **syncthing.service** in **/etc/systemd/system/** containing this:

```
[Unit]
Description = Syncthing service description (todo)
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /home/msa/syncthing/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Then I ran this command:

```
systemctl enable syncthing.service
```

It returned, that a symbolic link was succesfully created, so I started the service:

```
systemctl start syncthing.service
```

It didn't work. I ran this command:

```
systemctl status syncthing
```

and got this:

```
root@MinecraftServerAdvanced:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status syncthing.service
● syncthing.service - Syncthing service description (todo)
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/syncthing.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-05-06 19:47:54 CEST; 4s ago
Process: 789 ExecStart=/home/msa/syncthing/start.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 789 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

kvě 06 19:47:54 MinecraftServerAdvanced systemd[1]: Started Syncthing service description (todo).
kvě 06 19:47:54 MinecraftServerAdvanced systemd[1]: syncthing.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/E
kvě 06 19:47:54 MinecraftServerAdvanced systemd[1]: syncthing.service: Unit entered failed state.
kvě 06 19:47:54 MinecraftServerAdvanced systemd[1]: syncthing.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@MinecraftServerAdvanced:/etc/systemd/system#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086)  I have transcribed the contents for you, but you may want to check for errors in transcription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify proper systemd unit type; have a look at this manpage [[1](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=)] and brief description on Archlinux Wiki [[2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Service_types)]. I think, that forking type will be working for your setup. You need to specify shell previously; like it is described here: [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146049/linux-start-up-script-in-systemd)].

Regardless your question; I do not see any reson for running shell script in this setup. Just specify the full execution path in `ExecStart`.

Comment: Thank You, I had then to include **User=foo**, but now it works :)